# Python - How to import a variable in a function from other file?

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, importerror

What I am wondering is how do I pass the variable - element, into the second file? So that I can use this element as a parameter in a function and also a value to define the location of a variable in array later.

Also, the variable - element should have the same value as 'i' both in file 1 and 2.

file 1: This is a part of my program.

```
def menu():
    existAccount = False
    element = 0

    print("Welcome to STLP Store!")

    print("1.Login\n2.Sign Up\n3.Exit")
    user = int(input("Enter(1-3): "))

    if user == 1:
        inputEmail = input("Enter Email: ")
        inputPassword = input("Enter Password: ")

        for i in range(len(customers)):
            if inputEmail == customers[i].getEmail() and inputPassword == customers[i].getPassword():
                existAccount = True
                element = i
                break

        if existAccount == False:
            print("Incorrect Email/Password")
            menu()

        loggedInMenu(int(element))
```

file 2:
Now, if I put 'element' in loggedInMenu() , it will say "unresolved reference 'element'". If I don't, it will say "Parameter 'element' unfilled'.

```
from STLPStoreMain import *
    def AppMenu():

    choose = input("Enter:")

    if choose == '1':
        #customers is a array which contain class objects. getEmail() is a method to access hidding information.
        print ("Email:", customers[element].getEmail())
        print("Password: " + "*" * len(customers[element].getPassword()))
        print ("Bill Address", customers[element].getBillAdd())
        print ("Credit Card Number:", customers[element].getCredNum())

        AppMenu()

    if choose == '6':
        loggedInMenu(element)
```

Comment: I'll have a look at answering properly later (time depending); but a question first: Will these py files (modules) be kept in the same directory?  Or is file 1 stored in a different location than the importing file (file 2)?

Comment: They are in the same folder. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Hello.  I've added an answer below - apologies for the timing (manic schedule).  If the answer helps, please upvote **and accept** as the answer.  If not, let me know and I'll update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Passing a value from one file (module) to another.

To address your question of passing a variable from one module to another, I have taken the `class` approach, where the variable you want `file2` to access (`element`) is a *property* of `file1`.

#### The setup:

- Both files are placed into the same directory, which contains an `__init__.py` file.
- On instantiation, `file2` creates an instance of `file1`, which runs your login script, and stores the `element` property into a class attribute of `file2`.
- Next, the menu is called, and uses the `self._element` attribute which was created in `file1`.

Here's the code and it's honestly **much** simpler than the description seems.

#### Cleanup Edits:

Additionally, (discard them if you like) I've made a couple of PEP/Pythonic edits to your original code:

- Changed the `if` statement to use the `all()` function, which tests for all conditions in the list to be `True`.
- Updated code to use pure lower case - except for the class, which is camelcase.
- Updated your `if existAccount == False:` statement to the more Pythonic `if not existaccount:`.

#### file1.py

As I don't have access to your customers, a simple `_customers` dictionary has been added for testing.  Throw this away and uncomment your lines which access your `customers` object.

```
class StartUp():
"""Prompt user for credentials and verify."""

def __init__(self):
    """Startup class initialiser."""
    self._element = 0
    self._customers = [{'email': 'a@a.com', 'password': 'a'},
                       {'email': 'b@b.com', 'password': 'b'},
                       {'email': 'c@c.com', 'password': 'c'},
                       {'email': 'd@d.com', 'password': 'd'}]
    self.menu()

@property
def element(self):
    """The customer's index."""
    return self._element

def menu(self):
    """Display main menu to user and prompt for credentials."""
    existaccount = False

    print("\nWelcome to STLP Store!")

    print("1.Login\n2.Sign Up\n3.Exit")
    user = int(input("Enter(1-3): "))

    if user == 1:
        inputemail = input("Enter Email: ")
        inputpassword = input("Enter Password: ")

        # for i in range(len(customers)):
            # if all([inputemail == customers[i].getemail(),
                    # inputpassword == customers[i].getpassword()]):
        for i in range(len(self._customers)):
            if all([inputemail == self._customers[i]['email'],
                    inputpassword == self._customers[i]['password']]):
                self._element = i
                existaccount = True
                break

        if not existaccount:
            print("incorrect email/password")
            self._element = 0
            self.menu()
```

#### file2.py

```
class AppMenu():
"""Provide a menu to the app."""

def __init__(self):
    """App menu class initialiser."""
    # Display the startup menu and get element on class initialisation.
    self._element = StartUp().element
    self._customers = [{'email': 'a@a.com', 'password': 'a', 'addr':
                        '1A Bob\'s Road.', 'cc': '1234'},
                       {'email': 'b@b.com', 'password': 'b',
                        'addr': '1B Bob\'s Road.', 'cc': '5678'},
                       {'email': 'c@c.com', 'password': 'c',
                        'addr': '1C Bob\'s Road.', 'cc': '9123'},
                       {'email': 'd@d.com', 'password': 'd',
                        'addr': '1D Bob\'s Road.', 'cc': '4567'}]
    self.menu()

def menu(self):
    """Provide an app menu."""

    choose = input("Enter: ")

    if choose == '1':
        # customers is a array which contain class objects. getemail() is a method
        # to access hidding information.
#        print ("email:", customers[element].getemail())
#        print("password: " + "*" * len(customers[element].getpassword()))
#        print ("bill address", customers[element].getbilladd())
#        print ("credit card number:", customers[element].getcrednum())
        print('-'*25)
        print ("email:", self._customers[self._element].get('email'))
        print("password: " + "*" * len(self._customers[self._element].get('password')))
        print ("bill address:", self._customers[self._element].get('addr'))
        print ("credit card number:", self._customers[self._element].get('cc'))
        print('-'*25)

        self.menu()

    if choose == '6':
        # loggedinmenu(element)
        print('Not implemented.')
```

#### The output:

```
# Create an instance of the menu and run login.
am = AppMenu()

Welcome to STLP Store!
1.Login
2.Sign Up
3.Exit

Enter(1-3): 1

Enter Email: b@b.com

Enter Password: b

Enter: 1
-------------------------
email: b@b.com
password: *
bill address: 1B Bob's Road.
credit card number: 5678
-------------------------

Enter: 6
Not implemented.
```

Comment: I kind of understand it now. Thank you very much and that really helped me a lot.